# SQL Select Records From Current Month Only

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to write a query that returns the records that only exist once within a certain date range. There can be multiple identical records in this table that have different dates. For example:

```
Field |   Date
------------------
  A   | 2016-04-01
  A   | 2017-06-01
  A   | 2018-06-01
  B   | 2017-06-01
  B   | 2018-06-01
  C   | 2018-06-01
```

In this example, I would only want to have the query return the row:

```
Field |   Date
------------------
  C   | 2018-06-01
```

because there are no other rows with a Field value of 'C' that have earlier dates. I cannot simply query the table for dates greater than some value because there may exist records that match that criteria but have identical records with prior date values. I only want to return records that only exist once. This is a DB2 table and this query will eventually be built into an SQLRPGLE program.

Does anybody have any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You question is not very clear. You say that "There can be multiple identical records" but you then say they "have different dates". If two things are identical, then they (by definition) have no differences..     I.e. in your example there are no identical records!     Anyway I'm confused...  others my fair better!

Comment: When I say 'identical records', I mean that the records are identical in every way except for the date. All the fields are exactly the same and just the date value is different.

Comment: OK. so the answer by Alexandr is what you want. Just need to group by all your fields (of which you only have 1 in this example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `Field` and take those fields that occur only once. Here I take `max(Date)` because I don't want to group by it. Since it's the only date in the group, the `max()` function returns the date itself.

```
declare @from_date date = '20180101', @to_date date = '20180201'

select Field
       max(Date) Date
from   my_table
where  Date between @from_date and @to_date
group by Field
having count(Date) = 1
```

EDIT: @from_date and @to_date were set to datetime type, set it to date instead. Thank you @Clockwork-Muse!

Comment: Please [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Answer (score 1):

Using Group by in the inner query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE field 
IN 
    (SELECT field FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY field HAVING COUNT(*)=1) 
    AND date_ts >= '2016-01-01' 
    AND date_ts < '2019-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

select * 
from table x
where month(x.date) = month(current date)
and year(x.date) = year(current date);

Comment: This will not work. This only selects records that exist in the current month and year. It does not exclude the same record that exists with earlier dates. In my above example, this query would select records with a Field of A, B, and C. I am only looking to get C.